# How to update an entity created when user account information gets updated

Tags: rules

I have created an entity form the user registration page and called it application. The entity is created with the rules module and listed as an application on an extra content type in the content section.

what I need to do now is to update the entity when the user is updating his user account information. 
In this  case the entity  is created  creates a node of type Application  and the authors account  fields are mapped  into this content type.

I have played around with rules a lot but it seems I can't find out the trick!

If you know how to update a specific entity related to an author when the authors account gets updated I'll be very pleased to see your answer.

Thank you in Advance!

Josh

Comment: an entity can be various things, please be more specific.

Comment: This should  be  more  specific, now!

Comment: entity as in node, field, or...???

Comment: oh sorry. it's a node that has the account fields.